# Where did the psycopg2 name come from?

Tags: psycopg2

Every time I write

```
import psycopg2
```

I wonder why it is called psycopy2, because I always forget the true spelling? Is there any history I can know so that I could remember it clearly?

Comment: You're right. You have written psycopy2 instead of psycopg2. I don't know the origin of the name. What I use to remember it is thinking in a "psyco pig". Maybe it can help.

Comment: oh...It's too awkward...anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 33):

The quote below is by Federico Di Gregorio, the author of the package. After dealing with a badly written python+postgres driver in the company he worked for at the time, he wrote his own simplified version (psycopg) and:

> I wanted to call it psychopg (a reference to their  psychotic driver)
>   but I typed the name wrong.

I'm assuming the psycho in what would have been psychopg stands for psychotic while pg stands for postgres. So 'psychotic postgres'.

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA%2BRjkXFL6Jy7actUy%2BS%3DdGfjpuD_jpUYYofGpON%2B1Nq9S2Y75w%40mail.gmail.com#f9771ec89bf350e0594cf9640a1f912c)